# Cannot disable scroll wheel in gVim

Tags: vim

I'm using gVim in Windows 10.  It is the latest version (8.2) and that is the problem.  The scroll wheel never moved my cursor, before.  Vim is now essentially useless to me.  When I paste with the middle button (the scroll wheel) and it rolls the slightest amount, the cursor moves.  I've tried nmap,imap,vmap in _vimrc, and that changes nothing.  I'm going to be stuck in notepad if someone can't rescue me.

How to turn off the scroll wheel?  Please don't tell me to do anything in Windows, only vim.

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

`:help scroll-mouse-wheel` is helpful

Unfortunately, it says there's a difference between Win32 GUI and X11 GUI's.  In my X11 GUI on Linux, I can map the scroll wheel to a no-operation:

```
map <ScrollWheelUp> <nop>
map <ScrollWhereDown> <nop>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  It's a shame, I had really liked using gVim.

Comment: I want to question why you need to use the mouse at all though.   Using the mouse in Vim (or gvim) is an anti-pattern.   Cut and paste in Vim is called "yank and put" (it got those names decades ago) and done with the `y` and `p` keys.    Have you done `vimtutor` yet?   That will teach the yank and put operations.    You might also need to choose a setting for `set clipboard` to work with external programs.  See `:help clipboard` for more.

Comment: I've been using vim for decades, so I am familiar with quite a bit of it.  I like to paste with my middle mouse button, like in xterm.